# JS: How to open 2 links from current web page

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I need to create bookmark to my browser that will open link with id:

```
window.getElementById('updateOk').click()
```

and then (opens little window with another button)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('rmit-save-details btn btn-inline right  btn-green')[0].click();
```

how can I connect these two to work in one click in Chrome browser? I understand that the 2nd script must wait some time (maybe 0,5 seconds will be enough) and I even find setTimeout function but I just can't do that working... Nothing happens after clicking. When I click to bookmark with just one js script, it's working.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you mention a fiddle/link to better understand it?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a callback function on clicking over the first element.

```
 document.getElementById('updateOk').addEventListener("click",function(e){
   // return your other element callback here
   },false);
```

And within the callback put the exact same thing that you might be using for the click of `.rmit-save-details` element. It might be any submit event or whatever you want to do but it would work.

Comment: So, this is not working for me... `javascript:document.getElementById('updateOk').addEventListener("click",function(e){
   document.getElementsByClassName('rmit-save-details btn btn-inline right  btn-green')[0].click();
   },false);`